# Custom editable point in Google Maps Polyline

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I have an array of coordinates which length is about 3k. I draw the path with `google.maps.Polyline`. Is it possible to do each 100 (100, 200, 300 ...) point editable?

Comment: Yes, but not with the native [editable](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#editable) polyline functionality, you have to code that yourself.

Comment: @geocodezip i need to be able to edit my path, but not to add custom points over it.

Comment: Wolfgang Pichler has some examples that might help at: http://www.wolfpil.de/ (under Polylines and Polygons)